# XSLT 2.0, templates and node/value sets

Tags: xml, xslt

XSLT newbie (so I apologize in advance)

I have an XML file containing payment data. I am trying to transform it into an xml format used by a bank. The XML needs to be different if it's a non USD payment vs a USD payment. Multiple payments are possible in a given file
here is a sample of the source XML (simplified, one transaction)

```
<Payments>
 <Payment>
  <Payment_Detail>
     <Payment_Info>
        <ns:PAYMENT_Payment_Memo>Payment Info</ns:PAYMENT_Payment_Memo>
        <ns:PAYMENT_Payment_Amount>22222</ns:PAYMENT_Payment_Amount>
        <ns:PAYMENT_Currency>US Dollars</ns:PAYMENT_Currency>
        <ns:PAYMENT_Currency_Code>USD</ns:PAYMENT_Currency_Code>
        <ns:PAYMENT_Check_or_Advice_Number>0</ns:PAYMENT_Check_or_Advice_Number>
     </Payment_Info>
     <Payer_Data>
        <ns:PAYER_Company_Name>Company, LLP</ns:PAYER_Company_Name>
        <ns:PAYER_Address_Line_1>Main st</ns:PAYER_Address_Line_1>
        <ns:PAYER_Address_Line_2>Line 2</ns:PAYER_Address_Line_2>
        <ns:PAYER_City>Cleveland</ns:PAYER_City>
        <ns:PAYER_Zip_Code>11111</ns:PAYER_Zip_Code>
        <ns:PAYER_Country>US</ns:PAYER_Country>
        <ns:PAYER_Account_Number>1111-11111111</ns:PAYER_Account_Number>
        <ns:PAYER_Currency>USD</ns:PAYER_Currency>
     </Payer_Data>
     <Payee_Data>
        <ns:PAYEE_Name>Name</ns:PAYEE_Name>
        <ns:PAYEE_Bank_Name>Bank Name</ns:PAYEE_Bank_Name>
        <ns:PAYEE_Bank_Account_Name>Account Name</ns:PAYEE_Bank_Account_Name>
        <ns:PAYEE_Account_Number>1111111</ns:PAYEE_Account_Number>
        <ns:PAYEE_Masked_Account_Number>**********</ns:PAYEE_Masked_Account_Number>
        <ns:PAYEE_Account_Type>DD</ns:PAYEE_Account_Type>
        <ns:PAYEE_Routing_Transit_Number>22222</ns:PAYEE_Routing_Transit_Number>
        <ns:PAYEE_Bank_Country>US</wpc:PAYEE_Bank_Country>
     </Payee_Data>
  </Payment_Detail>
 </Payment>
</Payments>
```

my thought is/was to use a different template based on the currency. The problem I am running into is figuring out which template to call when there are multiple payments (a node set vs a single node)

here is my XSL (also simplified)

```
<xsl:variable name="paymentCurrency"
   select="/Payment/Payment_Detail/Payment_Info/ns:PAYMENT_Currency_Code"/>


        <xsl:choose> 
           <xsl:when test="$paymentCurrency = 'USD'">

                   <xsl:call-template name="Payment-Domestic"/> 

           </xsl:when>    
           <xsl:otherwise>

               <xsl:call-template name="Payment-Foreign"/>

           </xsl:otherwise>

       </xsl:choose>


         <xsl:template name="Payment-Domestic">
           <xsl:for-each select="/Payments/Payment">
               <paymentrec>
                   <recordType>2</recordType>
                   <!-- insert other domestic payment fields -->
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:template>

         <xsl:template name="Payment-Foreign">
           <xsl:for-each select="/Payments/Payment">
               <paymentrec>
                   <recordType>5</recordType>
                   <!-- insert other non US payment fields -->
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:template>
```

It works when there is  a single payment in the input file, but multiple entries set the variable to a node/value set and that will never match.

what is the best way to call the different templates?
should I not use the for-each? (treating XSLT like an imperative language isn't the smartest idea either, I know)

Thanks

---

EDIT to answer a comment / question
XSLT 2.0, sample output (simplified below)

(Foreign payment)

```
<paymentrec>
  <recordType>5</recordType>
  <payerAccNum>1111-11111111</payerAccNum>
  <Currency/>
  (other fields)
</paymentrec>
```

(USD payment)

```
<paymentrec>
  <recordType>2</recordType>
  <payerAccNum>1111-11111111</payerAccNum>
  <payAmount/>
  (other fields)
</paymentrec>
```

it also leads me to another question:
If I have 3-4 fields to add as a header to domestic payments (But not foreign). I have a domestic-pay template but if I call it inside the "domestic" template, it duplicates the header. If I apply it when I call the "payment" template it appears in the foreign payment (Which I don't want)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use multiple template rules like this:

```
<xsl:template match="Payment[Payment_Detail/Payment_Info/ns:PAYMENT_Currency_Code='USD']">
  <usa>
    ...
  </usa>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Payment">
  <restOfTheWorld>
    ...
  </restOfTheWorld>
</xsl:template>
```

No need for the extra "routing" template used by @thrig - template match patterns do that work for free.

Your code using

```
<xsl:variable name="paymentCurrency"   select="/Payment/Payment_Detail/Payment_Info/ns:PAYMENT_Currency_Code"/>
```

is wrong because path expressions starting with "/" select relative to the root of the document, not relative to the payment you are currently processing.

(And while we're on the subject of relative versus absolute, I avoided the terms "domestic" and "foreign" because you want your code to make sense to people outside the USA.)

Comment: Thank you! and the bank uses the terms "foreign" and "domestic"...and they have some really odd requirements I wont go into here

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ns="http://example.edu/" version="1.0">
  /* start at the root node... */
  <xsl:template match="/Payments">
    <root>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Payment"/>
    </root>
  </xsl:template>

  /* then for each "Payment" figure out what it is, call appropriate template */
  <xsl:template match="Payment">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="Payment_Detail/Payment_Info/ns:PAYMENT_Currency_Code='USD'">
        <xsl:call-template name="domestic"/>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:call-template name="foreign"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

  /* note that these are "rooted" relative to the Payment element */
  <xsl:template name="domestic">
    <domestic>
    <xsl:value-of select="Payment_Detail/Payment_Info/PAYMENT_Payment_Amount"/>
    </domestic>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="foreign">
    <TODO>
      <foreign/>
    </TODO>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: One last (related) question). If I have 3-4 fields to add as a header to domestic payments (But not foreign). I have a domestic-pay template but if I call it inside the "domestic" template, it duplicates the header. If I apply it when I call the "payment" template it appears in the foreign payment (Which I don't want)

Comment: Unclear to me without sample input and expected output; e.g. what happens if there are mixed region payments?